# Comparing number with list in python

Tags: python, compare

I want to number value with numbers in list and print that number if at least one element of list is same.Something like  this:

```
a= 1234
list = [12,21,32,12345,42394293489,12345,1234,9999]

if(something on list ==a):
 print a
```

and script in this example should do:

```
a!=list[0]
a!=list[1]
a!=list[2]
a!=list[3]
a!=list[4]
a!=list[5]
a==list[6]  # ok 
print a
```

Comment: Use `if a in list` to check whether the value is in the list. It is true if there is at least one occurrence of `a` in the list, and false otherwise.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't call a variable `list`, since that's the name of the `list` type, meaning you can no longer do, e.g., `my_list = list(my_tuple)`. As another side note, if the only reason you have this list is to search for values, you probably want a `set` instead of a `list`.

Comment: @Asad: Post that as an answer, because it pretty clearly is the right answer to his question.

Comment: @Asad: Sure, it's trivial, but there's really nothing else to say here. If it's a useless answer, then this is a useless question, so you're still better off writing the answer, then voting to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

To check whether an element is in a list, use the `in` operator:

```
if a in list:
    print a
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't know that python can do "if x in list"